# Wordpress 3.2: Hide Spam and Unapproved Comments form Contributors

Tags: wordpress, comments, restrictions

We're using Wordpress for a School Project. Every Student has his own Contributor account. The teacher holds the admin role and approves comments on the blog. Due to Spam and not so nice comments we need to watch for bullying comments to articles.

Is there a way to filter those unapproved and spam comments and show only approved comments to the students?

Comment: To clarify what the original poster is requesting for anyone else who is able to help: You technical issue is this: Your setup of Wordpress is that all students are set up as contributors. You want them to post comments, but kids being kids, you don't want the student to be offended by what some other students may say therefore you want a way to stop comments from being seen at all by anyone except the author of the comment till it is approved by the teacher. I've tried out your scenario and have not been able to help with a solution. I thought User Role Editor plugin would help, but to no ava

Answer (score 1):

WordPress provides an array of [moderation options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Comment_Moderation#Controlling_Moderation). If you would like every comment to be held for moderation, check the **An administrator must approve the comment** option, listed under **Before a comment appears**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Problem is, I want to hide Comments from Contributors. If they log in, the Users still will see unapproved comments. So, this is not a solution for my Problem.

Comment: @user971056 Users can always see their own comments, whether approved or awaiting moderation. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Users see their own and the comments of other users in the WP Backend. That's the Problem...

Comment: @user971056 I don't understand. Why do your users have permissions to log in to the WP back end?

Answer (score 0):

@user971056 I can't see a way to do this unless you change them from being Contributor level users. However, I would suggest you install GASP (Growmap antispambot plugin) which uses a client side 'tickbox' on comments to stop automated spambots posting spam in the first place - seems to be 100% effective.

Then use a plugin like Antispam Bee to automatically delete any human spam that gets through (set to strict filtering) and disable pingbacks/trackbacks to get rid of spam links to dodgy gambling/adult sites. Combination of above should stop your students seeing spam (but human bullying comments would still need reviewing)

Or stop allowing contributor level access to wordpress backend.